# Set time to default in openerp

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

I have defined a field called 'datetime'.

Here the time should be set to 08:00 by default and date we need to set manually.

How can we do this ?

I did something like this, here am setting date & time by default. But unable to set only time.

```
_defaults = {
'date_start': lambda self,cr,uid,context=None: fields.date.context_today(self,cr,uid,context) + " 02:30:00",  
}
```

Please Suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try following,

```
from datetime import datetime

_defaults = {
'date_start': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " 08:00:000",
}

### Suppose user will input start date in date_start field then your code should be like this,
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    date = vals.get('date_start',False)
    if date:
        vals.update({'date_start':date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " 08:00:000"})
    return super(class_name, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks, actually what i need is date should be set manually from user and time should be set to 8 o' clock by default.

Comment: Then you need to override create method and update data with user input and merge time as we did above.